# How to do incremental development with DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We're currently investigating a proper key-value store to store feed data. As we're hosting on AWS, their DynamoDB key-value solution looks very tempting. But, its seems that a DynamoDB table structure is unmodifiable after creation, making it really cumbersome to have rolling updates. Also even whilst not live it seems to be very painful to just copy all your indices manually in order to add an index to your table. Maybe I'm missing some kind of automation tool somewhere?

Comment: avtomation tools are [aws cli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB recently announced that online indexing will be coming soon, so you will be able to add indexes when you need them rather than all of it at table creation time. Here is the relevant section from this [source on 08 Oct 2014](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/):

> Online Indexing (Available Soon) We are planning to give you the
>   ability to add and remove indexes for existing DynamoDB tables. This
>   will give you the flexibility to adjust your indexes to match your
>   evolving query patterns. This feature will be available soon, so stay
>   tuned!

**Update 2015/1/27**: [Online Indexing is now available](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-update-online-indexing-reserved-capacity-improvements/)

Answer (score 0):

`DynamoDB` tables have not any structure, only primary keys and indices.
You should create your architecture before any tables.
Think, then do.

Anyway `AWS` have a flex API, you can write your own scripts or use [aws-cli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) for automation.

Comment: The indices looks pretty much like a structure to me... And honestly, when was the last time you have written something without any change requests later?

Comment: Using of indices makes DynamoDB very expensive. Anyways it is very slow and we must to cache everything everywhere. So indices are unusable.